# Can't update view in StackedWidget

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using stackedwidget and for some reason i cannot be able to update a view.I used this to get to my first view
(manage_employee_data).

```
connect(ui.actionManage_Employees_Data, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(manage_employee_data()));
```

Here is the code i am using to update the view.

```
void employed::manage_employee_data()
{
    tablesModel = new QSqlTableModel(ui.empds_tableview);
    tablesModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    tablesModel->setTable("employee_datastores");

    ui.empds_tableview->setModel(tablesModel);

    ui.empds_tableview->setColumnHidden(tablesModel->fieldIndex("id"), true);
    ui.empds_tableview->setColumnHidden(tablesModel->fieldIndex("employee_datastore_description"), true);

    ui.empds_tableview->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    ui.empds_tableview->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui.empds_tableview->setSortingEnabled(true);

    ui.empds_tableview->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    ui.empds_tableview->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

    tablesModel->select();
    //Localized Header Captions
    tablesModel->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Employee DataStore Name"));

    connect(ui.empds_tableview->selectionModel(),
            SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex&,
                                     const QModelIndex&)),
            this, SLOT(updateView()));

    ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui.page_10);

}

void employed::updateView()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Manage Employee Data Sent Me.");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it ? You can answer your own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui.page_10);` to my update function.

```
void employed::updateView()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Manage Employee Data Sent Me.");
    msgBox.exec();
    ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui.page_10);
}
```